# How can we resolve firebase functions INTERNAL exception in a flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a flutter app using firebase firestore and firebase functions.I am getting this exception again and again -

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL
E/flutter (15454): #0      catchPlatformException (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:19:3)
```

I have tried to resolve this exception since last few hours but unable to make any progress. This the code for my function from index.js file.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
        await admin.firestore().collection("collection_name").add({
          name: "my_name",
          email: "my_email" 
        }
        );
    });
```

This is my dart code for flutter app.

```
                MyButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    HttpsCallable a =
                        FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("addUser");
                    final x = await a();
                    print(x.data);  
                  },
                ),
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5):

I thought you only meant client side. But to recap what Yadu wrote you should handle it in the cloud function as well. Something like this:

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
  try {
    await admin.firestore().collection("collection_name").add({
      name: "my_name",
      email: "my_email" 
    }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', "some message");
  }
});
```

and on client side:

```
HttpsCallable a = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("addUser");

try {
  final x = await a();
  print(x.data);  
} on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
  // Do clever things with e
} catch (e) {
  // Do other things that might be thrown that I have overlooked
}
```

You can read a bit more about it on https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

Client side description is available under the section: "Handle errors on the client"

Comment: Thanks for your help ,already tried doing it , but the error message is not helpful [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL.

Comment: I edited my response with a description together with what Yadu meant. If this doesn't work, be sure to post your code where you handle the exceptions.

Comment: I have now put everything in try catch block , and I am throwing https error in the index.js file. But I think there is some other issue with my code, when I comment out everything except admin.firestore() ,I still get error. Can you give some ideas why this is happening ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to catch errors and rethrow them as `functions.https.HttpsError`. That's nothing new. Literally, everyone's answer in this thread includes this. Hovewer what's I've recently discovered are **special defined requirements for error code of HttpsError.**

**It appears that it can't be any string, but one of the values of `FunctionsErrorCode` enum.** Possible values are listed here:

```
"ok" | "cancelled" | "unknown" | "invalid-argument" | "deadline-exceeded" | "not-found" | "already-exists" | "permission-denied" | "resource-exhausted" | "failed-precondition" | "aborted" | "out-of-range" | "unimplemented" | "internal" | "unavailable" | "data-loss" | "unauthenticated"
```

More on:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https#functionserrorcode

Hope it helps someone, though it's not a new question.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps, with a callable firebase function, the message **[firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL** message can sometimes mean that you've spelled or capitalized your function name incorrectly in the client code, and it doesn't exactly match the function name on the server.

Or that you've deployed to a non-default region, and your client side code needs to explicitly call to that region. eg.

```
exports.createUser = functions.region("australia-southeast1").https.onCall( async (data) {...etc})
```

So the try/catch and all the error checking inside the cloud function means nothing because the function never actually gets called. The error message is very unhelpful!

Comment: Thanks, miss spelled the path. They couldn't just give an error back that says that it couldn't find this path :S

Answer (score 0):

the internal exception is because you are not handling the error in your function, use try catch in your function, wrap your whole logic in try, catch it and rethrow a `functions.https.HttpsError` which will be handled by firebase accordingly, this is because firebase expects `HttpsError' not any other error which will end up in being Internal error on client side

Comment: I have put my dart code in try catch block , and put the index.js code with functions.https.HttpsError , but still I am getting Firebase INTERNAL error. I am using nodjs 8 runtime

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issues by handling the **FirebaseFunctionsException** "INTERNAL".
Just wrap your code with **try**,**catch** block.

***Example***

```
  try {
      final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance
            .httpsCallable('deleteUser')
            .call({});
      } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
        print(error.message);
      }
```

Follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client) for more details.